# How do I import a file in python?

Tags: python, import

I am trying to import a python file
like this

```
import tiny

tiny.create_window('test')
```

and inside tiny is

```
from tkinter import *

def create_window (Name='Window'):
    window = Tk()
    window.title(Name)
    return window
```

but when I run it gives an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Harry\Documents\python files\tests\test4.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tiny
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tiny'
```

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: What IDE/editor are you using? how is your project directory structured? 
This is likely where the issue lies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your *"tiny.py"* file in **the same** directory as your main *"test4.py"* file? 
In this case are both your tiny.py and test4.py files in

> C:\Users\Harry\Documents\python files\tests\

Python interpreter doesn't know what directories to search in to find the file.
Thus **both your files must be in the same place** for the interpreter to know where to find them.
Alternatively you can look up some tutorials on creating modules and packages but that is a bit more advanced.